# Convert weird angles to Unity Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

So as the title suggests for some project of mine I need to use some angle (coming from an unreal engine game i believe) and rotate a Unity GameObject.

This seemed pretty straight forward except they don't work the same at all...
A picture is worth a 1000 words so here comes the drawing:

[image: weird angle / unity]

Any help is hugely appreciated! Thanks

Edit: trying to give an example

As the picture states how both system works, imagine i'm given an angle of 45 degrees, if i just used it straight into unity it would not be facing the same direction as the other system.

In the source, 45 degrees would be South East but would end up translated as South West in unity. if that makes more sense?

Comment: your question is very unclear. What exactly are you doing and how exactly does the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: i've edited the question and added an example

Comment: So one uses the _right-handed_ rule, the other _left-handed_.  Pretty easy to convert

Comment: why are the 2 objects facing different directions to begin with? And do you just want to rotate the object on the y axis?

Comment: `180 - inputAngle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so indeed MickyD was right, i just didn't have the right words to do a proper search, i just needed to convert the input angles that was using right handed rule to a left handed rule.

me.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -inputRotation.y + 180);

thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a formula to convert your angles to unity rotations.
It is simple like this.

```
float rotation = 180 - angle;
```

Above formula will convert angles to unity rotations.

e.g.,
angle => rotation
45 => 135
90 => 90
-90 => 270
-180 => 360
180 => 0